# 3D mesh representation

Tags: python, 3d, mesh

Currently I'm developing a library to manage some stream of data, but at some point I'd like to represent my findings on 3d. I would like to develop a 3D view of my project:

[image]

I have: 
- All the 3D vertices of one single block 
- All the properties related with the object

The question is: Can I do this on python? Which library should I use? Is there any other solution rather than

Comment: 3D plotting is hard, I'd recommend not doing it yourself. Use existing tools like [VTK](https://vtk.org/) which have a Python API.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of display you are looking for.

- if you need to display it as scientific data, there is [VTK](https://vtk.org/) which propose a great variety of ways to display
- if you want to operate your 3d data, display and inspect it at the same time, you can go for [pymadcad](https://github.com/jimy-byerley/pymadcad)  (a lot of other modules are available for mesh manipulation only, but without display)
- if you want a highly flexible rendering pipeline, you can take a look at [moderngl](https://github.com/moderngl/moderngl), which is very close to the hardware reality by makes everything extremely simple
- if you want a high interaction and flexibility in displaying meshes, maybe a game engine, like [Panda3D](https://www.panda3d.org/) can be more convenient